# How to get the last date updated of postmeta?

Tags: php, database

I would like to know if have a way to get the last modified of a postmeta table. I tried to see in database, however I did not see a column with date last modified.

[image: postmeta]

Comment: For the whole table? I wondered if [SHOW TABLE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html) had this, but I just get null. It looks like it's not tracked in InnoDB.

Comment: @RodrigoFranco if you mean a column like the `post_modified` in the posts table, then as you could see, there's no such column in the (post) meta table.

Comment: why do you want/need this? What problem is it solving for you?

Comment: This meta_key 'validade' is a ACF field. Do you know the plugin Advanced Custom Field? Do you know if have a function that I can use to find the last date modified? I need this information because I do not know when I updated this fields in all posts products.

Comment: Do you back up your database regularly? You could look through old backups for the change.

Answer (score 1):

### No

**WordPress does not track that information. You can't find it because it does not exist.**

Unless you specifically wrote code to track when post meta was added/modified, that information doesn't exist, and it's rare that any plugin would implement this as it would result in a lot of data collection.

*It would also be obvious where that data was when looking at the database via PHPMyAdmin, which I and yourself did not see in the screenshot. **So this data was never recorded, does not exist, and cannot be used.** It would be a fools errand to continue the search.*

The best hope you have is to check backups of your site and compare them by date to get a rough estimate of how far back the data existed. Emails/receipts/invoices might also corroborate this, but nothing in WordPress exists to tell you when a post meta was created or last modified.

The only other thing, is the post creation date, the post meta creation date must be the same or newer, but not older.

Comment: This meta_key 'validade' is a ACF field. Do you know the plugin Advanced Custom Field? Do you know if have a function that I can use to find the last date modified?

Comment: if ACF stores that data which is _***extremely*** unlikely_, then you would need to ask in an ACF community, ACF is offtopic and you can't ask for help with ACF here. To my knowledge it does not, and the chance that it does is astronomically small. If you did not store that data anywhere yourself then this data does not exist. The only real answer you can ever get is "no, the only person who ever knew this was Rodrigo and he forgot".

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's not good news. The chances of you finding a way to do this are 1 in a billion. In future it would be better to either store an additional post meta with the date, or, to replace the `6 meses` with an expiration date. It's also possible you have corroborating documentation elsewhere such as emails, invoices and receipts